# batch normalization parameters update in multi gpu tensorflow code?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, distributed-computing, batch-normalization

I have written a multi gpu Cnn code

In [this link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/inception/inception/inception_train.py) 
they commented in line 249

> # Retain the Batch Normalization updates operations only from the
>             # final tower. Ideally, we should grab the updates from all towers
>             # but these stats accumulate extremely fast so we can ignore the
>             # other stats from the other towers without significant detriment.

but this code  of updating batch norm(in line 253) :

```
with tf.device('/gpu:%d' % i):
.
.
.
  batchnorm_updates = 
  tf.get_collection(slim.ops.UPDATE_OPS_COLLECTION,scope)
```

is done for all towers(GPUs)
 so what is the right place of this update?

Answer (score 1):

I think you understand the code incorrectly.

as the `for loop` in the [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/inception/inception/inception_train.py#L232-L261),

```
for i in range(FLAGS.num_gpus):
  with tf.device('/gpu:%d' % i):
    with tf.name_scope('%s_%d' % (inception.TOWER_NAME, i)) as scope:

      with slim.arg_scope([slim.variables.variable], device='/cpu:0'):

      ......

      batchnorm_updates = tf.get_collection(slim.ops.UPDATE_OPS_COLLECTION,
                                            scope)
```

the `batchnorm_updates`will be replaced after each `for loop`, so it just contains the last tower's Batch Normalization updates operations when the `for loop` is done.